# Need help in completing the proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using Fundamental Groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading a proof of Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.My proof boils down to show that if $p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$( where $a_i$ is non zero for atleast one $i$) is non vanishing monic complex polynomial of degree $n$ then the maps

> $f_1:S^1 \to S^1$ defined as $f_1(z)=z^n$ and $f_2(z):S^1 \to S^1$ defined as $ f_2(z)=\frac {p(z)}{\vert p(z)\vert}$ then $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not homotopic.

I am unable to prove that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not homotpic .Any ideas?

Comment: It is going to be hard to do anything in you don't write down what in the world $\;p(z)\;$ is...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Edited thanks!

Comment: @V Nice yet still not enough, as if $\;p(z)=z^n\;$ then $\;f_2(z)=f_1(z)\;$ and the claim is false. Something seems to be missing...

Comment: @DonAntonio: Edited,makes sense now? THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a proof by contradiction, the main assumption needed is that $p$ is nowhere vanishing. (This is necessary for $f_2$ to be well defined, and it implies that at least one $a_i$ is non-zero). What you have to know is that $f_1$ is not homotopic to a constant, since in the standard identification of $\pi_1(S^1)$ with $\mathbb Z$ the class $[f_1]$ corresponds to $n\in\mathbb Z$. But $f_2$ is evidently homotopic to the constant map $\frac{p(0)}{\|p(0)\|}$ via $H(z,t):=\frac{p(tz)}{\|p(tz)\|}$.